# Facebook app install custom parameters?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am trying to see if i can pass a custom parameter to the facebook connect install. I basically just want to know what page they installed the app from so that i can display custom content for them. I am using the fb:login-button method for people to access my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is a tab application you can use the signed_request to find out what page as well as if the user has liked your app.

More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/